# Edit apache configuration in docker

Tags: docker

First time docker user here, I'm using this image: https://github.com/dgraziotin/osx-docker-lamp

I want to make the apache in that container to use a configuration file from the host system. How do I do that?

I know I can use `nsenter`, but I think my changes will get deleted when the container is turned off.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best solution is using VOLUME.

```
docker pull dgraziotin/lamp
```

You need to copy `/etc/apache2/` from container to current directory in host computer. Then you can do this:

```
cd ~
mkdir conf 
docker run -i -t --rm -v ~/conf:/tmp/conf  dgraziotin/lamp:latest /bin/bash
```

On container do:

```
ls /tmp/conf
cd /etc/apache2/ 
tar -cf /tmp/conf/apache-conf.tar *
exit
```

On host computer:

```
cd conf
tar -xf apache-conf.tar
cd ..
# alter your configuration in this file and save
vi conf/apache2.conf
# run your container : daemon mode
docker run -d -p 9180:80 --name web-01 -v ~/conf:/etc/apache2  dgraziotin/lamp:latest
docker ps
```

To list conf content on Container use:

```
docker exec web-01 ls -lAt   /etc/apache2/
total 72
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1779 Jul 17 20:24 envvars
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 10 11:46 mods-enabled
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 10 11:45 sites-available
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7136 Apr 10 11:45 apache2.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 10 11:45 mods-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 10 11:44 conf-enabled
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 10 11:44 sites-enabled
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 10 11:44 conf-available
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   320 Jan  7  2014 ports.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31063 Jan  3  2014 magic
```

Use `docker exec web-01 cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to list content inside Container.

One the WEB page to test your environment.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 8):

You should use a `Dockerfile` to generate a new image containing your desired configuration.  For example:

```
FROM  dgraziotin/lamp
COPY my-config-file /some/configuration/file
```

This assumes that there is a file `my-config-file` located in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`.  Then run:

```
docker build -t myimage
```

And once the build completes you will have an image named `myimage` available locally.